# @Font-face not working?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Im having trouble trying to get the font-face style working locally. I know it should work locally as the folder I downloaded from font-squirrel renders correctly.

Ive copy and pasted everything exactly into the same folder structure supplied by fontsquirrel...

CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'URWClassicoItalic';
src: url('urw_classico_italic-webfont.eot');
src: url('urw_classico_italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('urw_classico_italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('urw_classico_italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('urw_classico_italic-webfont.svg#URWClassicoItalic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

#primary-navigation {font-family: 'URWClassicoItalic'; font-size:2em}
```

HTML

```
<div id="primary-navigation">TEST</div>
```

My font files are all in the root, same directory as my index file.

Any help would be brilliant, thankyou

Comment: humm... i always thought browsers used fonts installed locally on client OS

Comment: is your css file also in the root directory? Or is this style implemented in the index file?

Comment: no my CSS file is in an includes folder, its referenced correctly though as I can access it via viewing the source

Comment: in that case you need to implement the font-face url relative to the folder where the css resides. That would be `src: url('../urw_classico_italic-webfont.eot');` if it is one level above the root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@font-face urls that are specified in a separate CSS file must have a url relative to this CSS

for example:

```
src: url('../urw_classico_italic-webfont.eot');
```

if the CSS-file is one level above the folder, where the font-file is stored.